# Unity. How to change sprite in script

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a sprite to be changed on specific button, i've already tried this code:

```
#pragma strict

var velocity : int = 8;
var sprite : SpriteRenderer;

function Start ()
{
    sprite = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);
}

function Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        sprite.sprite = Resources.Load("mario_3", typeof(Sprite));
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * -1 * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        sprite.sprite = Resources.Load("mario_3", typeof(Sprite));
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

here i'm just interested in the sprite, i've got a multiple sprite splited but when i press the button to see if it works, the sprite disappears, i made a debug log on it to see what is going on and what it prompts is that script is being null when it tries to change.

i've seen some examples through the internet and they did not help, i also looked through the script reference and it does not seem to be that helpful in this case

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, does "mario_3" definitely exist in your Resources folder?

`Resources.Load` does not work unless it is in a Resources folder, per the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) (my bolding for emphasis):

> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null. Only objects of type will be returned if this parameter is supplied. **The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project**, extensions must be omitted.

Secondly, make sure to include any sub-folders in the path name (e.g. `Sprites/mario_3` if the sprite's path is `Resources/Sprites/mario_3`.

Finally, I'd recommend pre-loading these sprites (e.g. at Start) instead of every key press, as that could cause significant performance issues.

Comment: well.. the sprite comes from a splitted sprite called mario. and the sprite i want to use in it has the name mario_3 or 4, so i would have to set the path of the original sprite instead of the splitted one?

Comment: One easy tip to find the correct path of a file in Unity is to right-click it and (in windows) click "Show in Explorer", I assume there's a similar "Show in Finder" option if you're on a Mac. Then right-click on the file, and look at it's path.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the variables for sprites at the beginning of the script then set them in the inspector.

```
var spriteMario3: Sprite;
```

Then later you can use it inside your script:

```
sprite.sprite = spriteMario3;
```

But remember that you need to change the spriteMario3 from inspector in the UnityEditor.

I hope it helps you.

Your code would look like this:

```
#pragma strict

var spriteMario3: Sprite;
var spriteMario4: Sprite;

var velocity : int = 8;
var sprite : SpriteRenderer;

function Start ()
{
    sprite = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);
}

function Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        sprite.sprite = spriteMario3;
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * -1 * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        sprite.sprite = spriteMario4;
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought on that solution, but thoses are not going to be the only sprites ill use, i have too many from one sprite

Comment: Then you could use Nick's answer, put your spritesheet in the "Assets/Resources" folder, then you can call using Resources.Load("mario_3", typeof(Sprite));